# how to sort file with hangul characters in linux?

Tags: linux, sorting, unicode

I have file which contain many hangul characters. for example:

```
저
가
항
공
사

인
도
의
항
공
사
```

I want to use linux sort for sorting lines in file but sort doesn't work.
It give me:

```
저
가
항
공
사
인
도
의
항
공
사
```

So, sort only sorts spaces.
How to sort this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is related to the LANG environment variable of your system.

In order to sort hangul characters, LANG should be set to ko_KR.utf-8.

`LANG=ko_KR.utf-8 sort tmp.txt`

should suit your need:

```
가
공
공
도
사
사
의
인
저
항
항
```

:D

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware of another Korean locale, **ko_KR.euckr**.

Recently, It seems most of distro uses ko_KR.utf-8 as default Korean locale but ko_KR.euckr is still used widely.